# writing on the wall on behalf of my fanpage

Tags: facebook, fan-page

I am writing an application that has to publish a message on the wall on behalf of my FB fanpage.

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId'  => 'xxx',
        'secret' => 'xxx',
));

$facebook->api("/100002240625255/feed", 'POST',  array(
        'message' => 'tu wiadomosc'
));
```

works, but the author is the owner of the table entries and not fanpage. Does anyone else have a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Piotr Zawadzki answer but I would recommend you to, before generating the page access token with your user access token, please, first be sure to use your Extended Access Token, for example with the following code in PHP:

```
$facebook->setExtendedAccessToken();
$fb_access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
```

This would allow you to create a non-expiry token for pages.

Answer (score 1):

You have to give a manage_pages permissions to one of the admins of the fanpage, by calling:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=[YOUR_APP_ID]&redirect_uri=[YOUR_URI]&scope=manage_pages,publish_Stream&response_type=token
```

With the token you receive, you can fetch the current user's fanpages with associated access tokens by calling:

```
/me/accounts?access_token=[received_token]
```

Then you can finally post to the fanpage's wall as a fanpage by calling

```
/[fanpageId]/feed?access_token=[fanpage's accesstoken]
```

You can find the tutorial over here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/
under Page Login

Comment: Perfect answer!  Good job @Piotr. Upvote it for you to get some points  :)